# python 2.6 TkInter combobox selection firing multiple times

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter

I have a combobox in a display manager object:

```
self.recentcmd_labeltext = StringVar()
self.recentcmd_combobox = ComboBox(self.frame, dropdown=1, editable=1, variable=self.recentcmd_labeltext)
self.recentcmd_combobox['command'] = self.cb_enter_command
self.recentcmd_combobox.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N+S+W+E, pady=5)
```

My combobox callback looks like this:

```
def cb_enter_command(self, event=None):
    self.controller.apply_command(self.recentcmd_labeltext.get())
```

My problem is that 
    self.controller.apply_command()
gets called twice when the user selects an item from the combobox with the mouse; but only once when the user types the item into the combobox and presses enter.  I'm not clear why this is the case.  I have tried using the widget without the link to the StringVar() - simply accessing the string through the selection attribute on the combobox, but that makes no difference.  Can someone clarify for me?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing information from the event to see what events are triggering it?

Comment: @mglison: Strangely the 'event' object is an empty string ?

Comment: try `repr(event)` to make sure that it's actually a string...

Comment: @mglison:  type(event) returns <type 'str'> and repr(event) seems to return the value selected by the widget.  (Same on both invocations.)  I must have botched my last test, because now the event obj seems to contain the string value selected in the widget.

Comment: More than a month later, I have no answer.  I ended up creating a conditional, that if the same button were pressed more than once within a certain time duration, to only execute the callback once.  Sad and ugly way to deal with it.